# Is Dart truly parallel or is it concurrent

Tags: javascript, dart

I have just found about Dart from Google and wanted to know if true parallelism can be obtained using Dart. From what I know my answer would be no because finally it runs just as Javascript(I cannot comment about how it run on the Dart VM) but then why the design decision of introducing async and await keywords?
Will this become something like Erlang?

Comment: What exactly does "true parallelism" mean to you? Multiple electrons moving at the same time in the CPU?

Comment: No, I mean that multiple threads executing to run the code. Concurrency does not mean the same.

Comment: For what it's worth - plain JavaScript has `async` and `await` keywords now too. In both languages, it's just syntax sugar over other async primitives (Futures in Dart, Promises in JS).

Comment: "*why the design decision of introducing async and await keywords?*" - I don't understand, you could need those both for multi-threaded and single-threaded concurrency?

Comment: async makes it easy to write, debug and understand concurrent code. Most of the popular concurrent and parallel platforms already use async and await. I think maybe with the introduction of Atomics and ShareMemory in ECMAScript 2018 sometime later this should become parallel.

Answer (score 8):

A Dart application can consist of one or more isolates. Isolates run as threads (other implementations are possible) and run parallel (also on different CPUs). Communication between isolates works with message passing.

Code within a single isolate is single-threaded and there is no parallelism at all. The execution is event-driven. See also https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop

`async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar to make async code look more like sync code, but it doesn't make code running sync.

Comment: So as you said I think this is just like the HTML5 Web Workers. Am I wrong in thinking so ?

Comment: Yes, it's quite similar.

Comment: So is the answer yes or no?

Comment: The question is way too unclear to give a yes/no answer. The above answer should give all the information required to derive if this meets your requirement. If not, please tell what exactly is unclear.